# maximizing lagrangian with matrix contraints.

Tags: optimization

$\max_\limits{S} \sum_{j=1}^kS_j^TKS_j $ 
$s.t\ S^TS = I$ where $S = (S_1, .., S_k),\ S_i\ (nx1)$

Not sure how to solve this problem since it cannot form a lagrangian equation due to conformability issues.

Comment: what are the properties of $K$?

Comment: symmetric and psd.

Comment: If you treat $S^TS=I$ as an orthonormality constraint, and try to optimize $\sum_{j=1}^kS_j^TKS_j +\lambda(S^TS-I)$ for S, you will find  that the $S$ are eigenvectors of $K$.

Comment: check the dimensions of the objective, that won't work. Maybe breaking down the $S^TS$ into two summations one along diagonal other off-diagonal.

Comment: Yes in the end it is spectral decomp of K taking the first highest e-values. Just wanted to figure if there is a nice way to put that constraint into the lagrangian.